# kubectl completion bash with Ancible

Tags: bash, ansible

I am new to ansible, please bear with me.

I have the following shell commands for bash completion.

I want to achieve that with Ansible.

```
apt-get install net-tools bash-completion -y
kubectl completion bash >/etc/bash_completion.d/kubectl
echo 'source <(kubectl completion bash)' >> /etc/bashrc
```

I am stuck with the middle one. The first and last I know how to write in Ansible.

```
kubectl completion bash >/etc/bash_completion.d/kubectl
```

Basically as I understand(I am new to bash scripting as well) the output to the command

```
kubectl completion bash
```

should be written to the file /etc/bash_completion.d/kubectl

It should be simple I guess. If some one can nudge me in the right direction, it would be helpful.

Comment: sooo why not `COMMAND: kubectl completion bash >/etc/bash_completion.d/kubectl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Ansible command module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html) will not work, as stated in the doc :

> The command(s) will not be processed through the shell, so variables like $HOSTNAME and operations like "*", "<", ">", "|", ";" and "&" will not work.

You should rather take a look at [Ansible shell module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html), especially the [examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#examples) provided.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
- name: Execute the command in remote shell and write the output in the specified remote file
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: kubectl completion bash > /etc/bash_completion.d/kubectl
    # If you do not want to run this when the file already exists, add
    creates: /etc/bash_completion.d/kubectl
```